# Why does steam exiting a pressure cooker valve feel cool to the touch?

Tags: temperature, everyday-life, cooling

I made the surprising discovery that steam escaping a pressure cooker through a  screw-valve on top of the pot feels relatively cool: I can comfortably place my hand on the steam without getting burnt.

The same thing does not happen when I heat water in a kettle: The steam there is live and dangerous.

Does this happen because the steam loses energy when travelling through the valve? Or might this be an effect due to the water molecules being collimated when exiting the valve and therefore having their speeds point in the same direction (this kind of energy might no longer be heat, because it is low entropy)?

DISCLAIMER AND WARNING: Be careful if you plan on trying this at home! Your pressure-cooker might be a different model than mine. If in doubt whether the steam is harmless, avoid touching it!

Comment: Probably has something to do with the internal steam pressure being high enough pressure that it can expand a lot under atmopsheric temperature so that it significantly cools.

Comment: Steam from a rapidly boiling kettle can be well over 100C

Comment: Remember steam is invisible. What you are seeing is water vapor.

Comment: It seems similar to how hot, compressed, liquid refrigerant exiting a Thermostatic Expansion Valve (TXV) turns into cool, rare gas.

Comment: It seems similar to how [hot, compressed, liquid refrigerant exiting a Thermostatic Expansion Valve (TXV) turns into cool, rare liquid](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772613/10024).

Answer (score 1):

Whereas a kettle freely releases a large amount of water vapour, which converts rapidly to steam, a pressure cooker only releases steam as a safety mechanism. Ideally it would not release steam at all. The valve on a pressure cooker should (if everything is working correctly) only releases enough water vapour to keep internal pressure safe. As a result the pressure cooker is at a significantly higher temperature, and releases more heat through convection and radiation from the walls than does the kettle.

The amount of energy is proportional to mass (as well as temperature). Because there is much less steam being produced, there is much less mass. It cools more rapidly on contact with the air and carries far less heat to your hand. The effect you feel has more to do with energy (heat) than temperature.