# How high pressure, high temperature liquid refrigerant exiting a Thermostatic Expansion Valve (TXV) turns into low pressure, low temperature liquid?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, diffusion, low-temperature-physics

In a refrigerator or heat pump, how does high pressure, high temperature liquid refrigerant exiting a Thermostatic Expansion Valve (TXV) turn into low pressure, low temperature liquid? Is this a diffusion process?

[image: Figure2-2:DetailedRefrigerationCycle]

*Figure 2-2: Detailed Refrigeration Cycle*
Migliaccio, [*Refrigerant Charging and Service Procedures for Air Conditioning*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9654)